# Add screenshots, texts to a "SoundCloud App"

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, soundcloud

We use the `SoundCloud SDK` in our App so the user can upload sounds to its SoundCloud page easily.

We also created an App with our SoundCloud account, we can edit some of the App info like:

- the title
- a link to our website
- the token
- ...

But we're not able to add other info like other Apps do (add screenshot, some texts, ...)

How can it be done?

The App is currently in test, not submitted yet to Apple.

Comment: could be more specific? what you mean when you say "add screenshot, some texts" – is there an example app you are talking about?

Comment: Yes, any App in the "App Gallery", like this one: http://soundcloud.com/apps/figure

We are not able to do such things, the 'edit page' of our App doesn't allow more than what I've described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content for the app gallery is a part of the publication process, submissions for the app gallery are [no longer accepted](http://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/the-next-app-gallery-update):

> Moving forward, we'll be proactively reaching out to folks who meet this criteria about adding their apps to App Gallery instead of accepting mass submissions like we have in the past.